# Does Jenkins support clustering?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I am a user of hudson. I recently moved to jenkins. I know hudson does not support clustering of servers. Does jenkins provide that. Also elaborate things a little as I am new to this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean, having multiple build servers, or having multiple primary servers that can fail over if one goes down?

Answer (score 4):

If by clustering you mean having a single web interface and many workers behind, yes Jenkins (like Hudson from which Jenkins is forked) support it and it's called [Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds). It allows you to run jobs on differents workers called slaves.

See the [Distributed Builds page on the Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds).

Comment: However - it is worth noting that all data archived, and all log data from builds as well as web interactions (including API for the SOA bits) go via the master server - and this can not be clustered.

Answer (score 2):

OS Jenkins does not support clustering.

Cloudbees Jenkins Enterprise has HA support using active and stand-by Jenkins masters.

http://jenkins-enterprise.cloudbees.com/docs/user-guide-bundle/ha.html

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is fairly close to Hudson, feature-wise. Jenkins project forked off Hudson around 18 months ago and the basic architecture is still the same. So, even without knowing exactly what you mean by clustering, I am confident Jenkins does not support clustering if you say Hudson does not support it.

I have heard rumors there is work going on to make Jenkins have some high-availability features, but that is all I know. No idea what exactly that means or how is it implemented.